# Kotlin Language Server Does not recognize gradle dependencies

Tags: kotlin, neovim, ktor, language-server-protocol, nvim-lspconfig

I have recently switched to using AstroNeoVim. I have installed the kotlin_language_server LSP, Treesitter on my nvim and I saw changes after that. Now only issue i have is that LSP seems not to recognize classes that come from dependencies. I have no problem building and running my application with `gradle build/run` in terminal but nvim is still complaining.

[image: LSP errors displayed]

I tried:
installing different LSPs, but only kotlin_language_server seemed to work this far.
I checked that i have JAVA_HOME,
I ran app with gradle without any issues in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `gradle` files from the project like mentioned [here](https://github.com/fwcd/kotlin-language-server/issues/487#issuecomment-1782096036) fixed the issue.

```
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
gradlew
gradlew.bat
```

Still not completely sure why this creates an issue, I will post if I know more, also there is [this thread I created on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/18488k4/help_switching_to_nvim_for_kotlin_development/) with some more useful info for configuring nvim for kotlin